# Racket. Why it doesn't load the data with "require" when the data is defined in anoter file

Tags: racket

I have this in one file (the name of the file is ExamplesFile.scm):

```
(define examples (with-input-from-file "examples.scm" read))
```

I understand that the data is loaded and stored at the variable `examples`

If I execute:

```
examples
```

in the iteration window it gives the data that is at the file "examples.scm". That is working fine.

Later, in another file located at the same directory I write:

```
(require "ExamplesFile.scm")
```

In the iteraction window of this second file the functions defined at "ExamplesFile.scm" are available. But if I execute:

```
examples
```

I got this error:

```
examples: undefined;
 cannot reference an identifier before its definition
```

How can I solve it? How can I have the data that is read and stored in one file in the second file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make the `examples` binding in `ExamplesFile.scm` visible to other files that require it, you need to explicitly provide it, using (e.g.)

```
(provide example)
```

Alternatively, if you want to `provide` everything defined in the file, you can use

```
(provide (all-defined-out))
```

All of this is assuming that you're using the `#lang racket` language; you don't mention this explicitly.

Apologies if I've misunderstood something about your problem!